# How come some algorithms are better for GPU mining vs CPU mining?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-hardware, proof-of-work

How come some algorithms are better for GPU mining vs CPU mining?

From what I know (that may be wrong) most Ethereum miners use GPUs?

And bitcoin miners use CPU and ASIC mining?

What are the different algorithms out there Sha256, Scrypt, what others are being used?

And why some are better to mine with GPUs other's with CPU?

If one is to create a new PoW coin isn't there the danger that someone with a lot of ASIC mining power currently for bitcoin can just switch to your network and easily do a 51% attack and bring down your project?

How can one defend against that? Are there any algorithms that are not good to mine on ASICs?

Should a new Proof-of-Work coin use a new algorithm that most popular coins don't use?

Answer (score 1):

Both are computational units. Algorithms are typically written without making assumptions about underlying chips that are going to run those algorithms, but certain type of tasks can benefit from massive parallel processing that GPUs, which increases GPUs appeal in mining, machine learning, etc.

https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2009/12/16/whats-the-difference-between-a-cpu-and-a-gpu/

Specific explanations about ML and mining can be found here:

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-use-expensive-GPUs-for-Bitcoin-mining-and-not-multiple-CPUs-like-Quad-Xeon

https://www.quora.com/Why-are-GPUs-well-suited-to-deep-learning